# Binding Component <-> Container (Enabled property)

Tags: java, binding, properties

I'm just trying to work out the best way to replicate a pretty useful feature of Windows' `Forms.Panel` in Java. Basically, when you disable a Windows `Forms.Panel`, all child control's are set to disabled too. However, their enabled property is *preserved* such that, when the the `Panel` is enabled again, any child control that was disabled before the Panel was disabled, *remains* disabled.

I can add a property listener for a `JPanel` to be triggered when it's enabled property is changed and then cycle through all the `JPanel`'s components and set them to disabled, but this wont preserve the component's enabled properties.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more complex solution can be found in the [Disabled Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/disabled-panel/) entry. Internally it uses a collection as suggested by mlk to track the components that where enabled. Even if you don't like the proposed solution you can still use the [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class to easily get all the components on the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Store the disabled components in a collection and check this collection when re-enabling them.